# How to use a css inline svg from an external file

Tags: css, svg, inline

I have an svg sprite sheet which I have created, and I use it on my page using the before parameter as I am using it for my div buttons. There is a lot more css than this, but this is the important bit.

```
.logout_button::before,
.vat_button::before{
    content: "";
    width: 1.563em;
    height: 1.563em;
    background: url("../../images/buttons/test.svg") 0px 0px no-repeat;
    float: left; 
    margin: -3px 10px 0px 0;
    background-size: 12.5em 12.5em;
}
```

Previously I was using png but I wanted the ability to change the colour of my button icons, so decided to change to svg to overcome this problem.
The problem is that I cannot change the colour of the css using this method.

I believe if I use an inline svg I can then change the css, but the problem is this. My svg sprite svg is 60k and I don't want a big wad of code poluting my css file.

Is there a way of including an svg in a separate file in my css without having a pile of inline code in my css file.

I don't really want to use jQuery for this, just css if that is possible.

I have searched an searched for an answer but nothing seems to come close.

Adding my svg to the html is not an option.It has to be in the css as a background image.

Just want to add that I don't want to use css masks as they are imcompatible in a lot of browsers, and take a lot more work to get it to work.

Comment: http://codepen.io/noahblon/post/coloring-svgs-in-css-background-images - maybe it will help you.

Comment: Pretty sure you just use a `url()` pointing to your svg file.

Comment: I am already pointing a a url to my svg file, but you cannot change the css by doing this. You can only change or over ride css if it is inline, but inline requires a big wad of code in my css file.

Comment: There is [a hack](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/5198257) which involves pointing to a different element of your svg, but I don't see why you don't want to include it in your html  markup, you would still be able to use as a background image if you point your url to the html file+id of the element.

Comment: I am loading in an svg sprite sheet. The css then changes the background position on each sprite. I have only shown the one icon in my example. If I put it in the html then I cannot access it from css.